# swift set more space between bar items

Tags: swift

in my swift 2 app i have to items on the left side of my item bar.
this is my code:

```
let CloseButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
            CloseButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)
            CloseButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"close"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            CloseButton.addTarget(self, action: "close", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            let leftBarCloseButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: CloseButton)

            let EditButton: UIButton = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.Custom)
            EditButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)
            EditButton.setImage(UIImage(named:"edit"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            EditButton.addTarget(self, action: "edit", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
            let leftBarEditButton: UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: EditButton)

self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([leftBarCloseButton,leftBarEditButton], animated: true)
```

this is the result:

[image]

how can i make more space between the "x" and pencil icon?

Comment: Does increasing the frame width do anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new Bar button item (fixed space) between these icons

```
var fixedSpace:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.FixedSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
fixedSpace.width = 10.0



self.navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItems([leftBarCloseButton,fixedSpace,leftBarEditButton], animated: true)
```